# Doing an array formula lookup

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a list of data like this:

```
Name   |    Number
Bob    |   300
Joe    |   200
Jane   |   400
Sisqo  |   450
Jill   |   500
```

There's about 62 rows of this, all numbers which can be different, some repeated. My goal is to basically add a column which contains all the list of people who are at 400 or above. So that it looks like this:

```
Name  
Jane 
Sisqo 
Jill
```

What I have is:

```
{=iferror(INDEX($A$2:$B$6, SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$6 >= 400, $B$2:$B$6,), ROW(1:1)), 1), "")}
```

What I imagine this is doing:
1) The small function is looking in range b2:b6, and because this is an array formula, looks at each cell in B2:B6 to see if its greater or equal to 400.
2) I don't know exactly how, but I hope that the row function is finding the array of b2:b6 only if the value in the cell under consideration is greater than or equal to 400. If it doesn't find anything, nothing happens. 
3) Then it runs the comparison small(b2:b6, 1) for the lowest value in that range. Then when copied down, because I'm using the row() function, it will be small(b2:b6, 2), small(b2:b6, 3) and so on.

At this point the row of the lowest number at 400 or below should be found.

So then the index function should read

```
index(a2:b6, 3, 1)
```

for the first one.Except I'm only getting

Name
Bob
Bob

So where is the error?

Comment: Are the names unique?

Comment: The names are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use MATCH in an Array form:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(1,(COUNTIFS($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$6)=0)*($B$2:$B$6>=400),0)),"")
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: that is a pretty cool answer.  Can you explain a bit more about how/why it works?

Comment: In particular why is doing =COUNTIFS($E$1:E3,$A$2:$A$6) different if you do it in an array formula vs the standard way

Comment: Hi scott, can you explain what's going on here? COUNTIFS($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$6)=0

Why the range $E$1:E1? Why the =0?

Comment: The end of the range is dynamic, so as it is dragged/copied down it will increase the referenced range in which we look to see if the data can be found.  Basically it looks to see if any of the values in column A exists in the range above the formula.  If it does it returns false which equates to 0.  Therefore the Match will find the first name that is not in the list above itself and is greater than the 400.  Thus giving a unique list of names in order of column A.  @bdpolinsky

Comment: the formula works in the way I need it to. Please correct me where I am wrong:

The COUNTIFS($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$6)=0) formula looks through all the names that have been found in the '

Comment: Yes, it is what ensures that the names are unique. @bdpolinsky