# Exact same formula results in different answer depending on where it is used

Tags: google-sheets-formula

**Questions**
How can the exact same formula, using the exact same inputs, give different result when written in different cells?

**Background**
I have a sheet which references a cell value via INDIRECT() to fetch two sets of data and compare them, and count the number of elements in data set 1 that is larger than the corresponding element in data set 2.

```
=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(ABS(FILTER(INDIRECT($X3); ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($X3))))); "<" & INDIRECT(CONCAT("AnotherSheet!";$W3)))
```

This works just fine most of the time. However, I am using this same equation in different columns to extract different information, for example just the number of points, how many percent of the total data-set is outside the limits and so on. Due to this I noticed that in a few places the number of data points could be 100 (out of 100) so that the percent should show 100%, but instead it shows 0%. Even though the only difference in the function is that the later is divided by the total amount of points.

**What I've tried**

I did some research and some stated that it could be due to formatting so I tried removing all formats. Did not work.
I tried clearing formatting of the data set.
I made sure that the references are correct and it is.
I tried copying it in different ways, just dragging the cell-handler, copy paste, copy-paste just the formula, tried copying just the format from the cell giving the correct response.

I tried removing the INDIRECT references for one range but the problem persists.

[Here is a link to a sheet where the issue is replicated with fabricated data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qfbfrKW1FF9WNt_qFJcQ_lyhB-1N5DTlDEC-Yem7HZo/edit?usp=drivesdk)
On the sheet named "Data_set2" in the range K57:AJ108 you can see the problem clearly. A shorter version of that range is also saved in this table below.

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8 | c9 | c10 | c11 | c12 | c13 | c14 | c15 | c16 | c17 | c18 | c19 | c20 | c21 | c22 | c23 | c24 | c25 | c26 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 |
| 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 | 240,00 |
| 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 0,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 | 235,00 |
| 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 | 302,00 |
| 104,00 | 101,00 | 101,00 | 101,00 | 107,00 | 107,00 | 104,00 | 104,00 | 102,00 | 101,00 | 101,00 | 101,00 | 100,00 | 100,00 | 98,00 | 97,00 | 97,00 | 96,00 | 91,00 | 91,00 | 97,00 | 97,00 | 97,00 | 97,00 | 100,00 | 101,00 |
| 244,00 | 245,00 | 245,00 | 245,00 | 245,00 | 247,00 | 247,00 | 247,00 | 247,00 | 247,00 | 247,00 | 251,00 | 251,00 | 251,00 | 251,00 | 251,00 | 251,00 | 248,00 | 250,00 | 251,00 | 251,00 | 246,00 | 245,00 | 246,00 | 246,00 | 245,00 |
| 288,00 | 288,00 | 289,00 | 289,00 | 289,00 | 289,00 | 289,00 | 289,00 | 289,00 | 289,00 | 290,00 | 293,00 | 293,00 | 293,00 | 294,00 | 294,00 | 294,00 | 294,00 | 295,00 | 295,00 | 295,00 | 294,00 | 294,00 | 294,00 | 294,00 | 294,00 |
| 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 | 207,00 |
| 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 | 296,00 |
| 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 | 256,00 |
| 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 | 229,00 |

Every cell in each row has the exact same formula, and every row just reference a different row in the Thresholds.

I know that I could "Get around this" by just doing the calculation in one cell and then just reference that cell but then I wouldn't know if it calculated it correct or not.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40598576/5479575) and its comments explains the [countif()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) behavior when an entire range is passed to its second parameter `[criterion]`. It maybe a excel based question but the scenario & workings attribute perfectly to GSheets as well

Comment: ah... Ofcourse! Thank you so much
Guess I'll have to work with some arrayformulas and if-statements instead.