# Table with 4 variable columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm sure this is simple for all of you, but I'm new here.  How do I create a formula or code that can output all of the potential scenarios for this type of array below?  Basically, max is 60, min is 0, but I'm unsure how to make Excel spit out a table that represents this.

[image: Table example]

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel/info you should be using the [excel-formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) tag but it also suggests [su] as a better place to ask about it. (They're cleaning up the table tag, you don't want to use that one.)

Comment: This might help you find your answer: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536926/doing-an-array-formula-lookup)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Doing it with Excel formulas alone, while theoretically possible, is incredibly computationally demanding and crashed Excel when I was trying to do so. You can do this fairly easy with VBA though.

Create a VBA module, drop these two snippets in, press play, and wait for a few seconds to a minute while the code runs. The code is not the most efficient, but it is probably the simplest algorithm to understand.

```
Public Sub comb4()
    Dim a, b, c, d, n, r, x As Integer
    x = 60
    a = x
    Do While a >= n
        b = x - a
        Do While b >= n
            c = x - a - b
            Do While c >= n
                d = x - a - b - c
                Do While d >= n
                    If sumToZero(-x, a, b, c, d) Then
                        r = r + 1
                        Cells(r, 1).Value = a
                        Cells(r, 2).Value = b
                        Cells(r, 3).Value = c
                        Cells(r, 4).Value = d
                    End If
                    d = d - 1
                Loop
                c = c - 1
            Loop
            b = b - 1
        Loop
        a = a - 1
    Loop
End Sub


Public Function sumToZero(ParamArray intNums())
    For x = LBound(intNums) To UBound(intNums)
        y = y + intNums(x)
    Next x
    If y = 0 Then sumToZero = True
End Function
```

### Code explanation:

`x` is the `max` that you defined, while `n` is the `min` you defined.
`r` is a counter which helps us track what row to print to.

Since we always want to count down to 0 for each column's sub-permutations, each of our `Do While` loops will count from the theoretical maximum value down to 0.

The loop structure is nested so that each time we hit -1 in a column *N* we instead leave the loop, go into the loop one level higher, and decrease the value in column *M* by 1. The value in *N* is reset when we start the next instance of the loop for *M*.

Between each value change we need to check to see if the result is a valid solution. We pass the (negative) `max` and all 4 variables we are looping to a function which sums the values and returns true if the variables are equal to the `max`. When the function is true, we go to the next row in Excel and print the four values.