# Concatenate Values from a Range based on a Lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a budget for a project with multiple phases. There is a possibility that not all phases will be worked on so I've added some lookups and SUMIF formulas so that I can get a summary of my included and excluded effort and dollar amounts. That all works fine. Now I'd like to hide my row of lookups (row 1), but still have a way of identifying which phases of the project are included and which are excluded. Obviously I could manually concatenate them together, but if the phases being included/excluded change then I need to remember to update those formulas (and it's not nearly as fun as doing all in a formula). Here's how my sheet looks:

[image: Table Layout]
The TEXTJOIN function seems like it should work (i.e. `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, C2:N2)`), but I can't wrap my head around how to make the range parameter dependent on my lookup row. I played around with INDEX using something like `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, INDEX(A2:M2,,(A1:M1="Yes")*COLUMN(A1:M1)))`, but didn't have any luck. At the end of the day I want to have something like:

> Phase 1
>    Phase 2
>    Phase 5

Please note that the above data should all appear in the same cell - using the line feed character, CHAR(10), as the delimiter in the TEXTJOIN function will make all of the phases appear on a new line within a single cell. I do not want to fill formulas through multiple cells. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please take a look at the picture. I had a similar issue in the past (and brought it to StackOverflow, at which point I was helped by @ScottCraner, original post here:
[Doing an array formula lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536926/doing-an-array-formula-lookup)

Basically, 
1) You set up the array you are looking through - in my case, its $A$2:$A$6, in your case it will be $B$2:$M$2.
2) You then nest the COUNTIFS function inside of a match function. The function does the following:
  A) It checks whether the name of phase X has already shown up in column E when you are copy/pasting down
  B) If it has, move on to the next one
  C) If it hasn't, output
3) Of note: this is an array formula, so the formula itself is checking through every cell. So it looks at cell A2; if the cell in B2 is "Yes", and "Phase 1" isn't in range in column E, then put in phase 1. Because it is, its there. Then it looks at cell A3; if the cell in B3 is "Yes", the same thing for phase 2. Then it looks at cell A4; because B4 is "No", the *(B2:B6="Yes") will throw an error. and so on
4) Place error catching brackets around the function.

Comment: I've edited my original question to clarify that I was hoping to have all of the results concatenated within a single cell as opposed to filling a formula through a range.

Answer (score 0):

A less elegant way to go about this, which doesn't require array formulas would be to use the secondary column's "Yes/No" as an index.  This assumes the value in the secondary column is redundant- and repeating the primary column's "Yes" or "No."

In C1: `=CONCATENATE(B1,COUNTIFS($A$1:B1,B1))` -
Repeat relatively for E1, G1, etc.

Somewhere separate (the below formula assumes Row 1 of the same worksheet), you could then use: `=IFERROR(INDEX($2:$2,MATCH(CONCATENATE("Yes",ROW()),$1:$1,0)-1),"")`

To look up "Yes1", returning "Phase 1" and autofill downward.  IFERROR is used here to return blank when you run out of "Yes" results.

Comment: The values in the secondary columns aren't redundant - they're being used in other SUMIFS calculations along with the Headers in row 3 to sum all of the included/excluded Time and Amounts. As well, I would like to have all of the values in a single cell as opposed to filling down the sheet.